# How to make a glowing effect visible to 1-2 people

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make SCP-939 from SCP Secret Laboratory. but I searched everywhere, but I cant find a way to make a glowing effect visible to 1-2 people only.How do I do this?

NOTE: I am on 1.12.2 and have no knowledge of coding, so the bukkit forums thing i found wont work.

Comment: you would have to use something other than the glowing effect

Comment: the glowing effect is the only thing I know about that lets people see entities through blocks. so what else would I use?

Comment: I did a bounty to try and figure this out, and i have been looking at the internet as well but I have yet to find my answer.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do this with just vanilla commands. With Bukkit, you can because you have the ability to send the effect packet to only specific players.

Comment: I do not understand what a "packet" is.As I said I don't know how to code so unless there is a plugin that I have not found then I am still waiting.

Comment: A packet is like, Bukkit tells one person that an entity is glowing but doesn't tell anybody else. Not sure how to pull that off without some code work though.

Comment: Then im still at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vanilla Minecraft does not have this ability, not even with command blocks.

You can see [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/glow-packets-per-player-help.257884) some discussion of how to **write a plugin** to do this (they had similar requirements to you); there's even an apparently-somewhat-maintained (though completely undocumented) [library](https://github.com/InventivetalentDev/GlowAPI) extant that'd help… but apparently no plugin **currently exists** to do this.

It looks like [*many* have tried](https://www.spigotmc.org/search/191064900/?q=per+player+glow&o=relevance&c%5Bnode%5D=52), but [all have failed](https://www.spigotmc.org/search/191064956/?q=per+player+glow&t=resource_update&o=relevance&c%5Bis_resource%5D=1), to write the plugin you're looking for.

Comment: huh guess u get the reputation...

Comment: @anomanous sorry for the disappointing answer… if I knew MCP/Java better, I'd have contributed something more helpful